# MySQL SELECT with IF statement to set variable from another table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to show all the results from Table1 based on some select condition being true, and have a variable be set to 0 or 1 for each result from Table1 based on some satisfied condition with Table2.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Some_Condition=true

Foreach Table1.Name
    SELECT IF(TID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Variable FROM Table2 
    WHERE 
        Table2.Name=Table1.Name AND Table2.Val='p'
```

How can I make this all into one SQL call?

example call I would like to see is:

Table1:

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID |        Name       |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  |        John       |
+----+-------------------+
| 2  |        Alan       |
+----+-------------------+
```

Table2:  So here `Alan` exists AND `Val='p'`, not just existing

```
+-------+-----------+-----+
|  TID  |    Name   | Val |
+-------+-----------+-----+
|   1   |    Alan   |  p  |
+-------+-----------+-----+
```

SQL result I want from a SINGLE SELECT statement:

```
+------+----------+
| Name | Variable | 
+------+----------+
| John |     0    |
+------+----------+
| Alan |     1    |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **LEFT JOIN** and a **CASE** statement may work for you.  Please see query below.

```
SELECT A.Name AS item, (CASE WHEN B.Val='p' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Variable 
FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON (A.Name=B.Name)
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know results. I think this is what I was looking for.  The actual query from A table is a bit more complicated, but I will try to merge this solution into it.

Comment: Thanks, this did what I wanted! I've not used CASE before, thanks for teaching me something new ;)

Comment: You're welcome!  Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a JOIN:

```
SELECT t2.Name, IF(Tt2.ID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Variable
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN
     Table1 t1
     ON t2.Name = t1.Name
WHERE t2.Val = 'p' AND <some condition on t1> = true;
```

In MySQL, you can simplify the `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT t2.Name, (Tt2.ID IS NOT NULL) AS Variable
```

Note that I added the name to the `SELECT`, although it is not in your sample SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need `LEFT JOIN Table2` to include all rows from `Table1` even if row in `Table2` not exists. And then in `Variable` column just check if `Table2.TID` is presented (i.e. not null).

```sql
SELECT Name, (Table2.TID IS NOT NULL) AS Variable
FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Name=Table1.Name AND Table2.Val='p'
```

Or it can be done with `IF()`:

```sql
SELECT Name, IF(Table2.TID IS NULL, 0, 1) AS Variable
FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Name=Table1.Name AND Table2.Val='p'
```